# Unable to start marathon status=1/FAILURE

Tags: mesos, marathon

Centos 7.1, Mesos 1.7.0, Not able to tell the marathon version

```
[node1]$ sudo rpm -Uvh http://repos.mesosphere.com/el/7/noarch/RPMS/mesosphere-el-repo-7-1.noarch.rpm
[node1]$ sudo yum -y install mesos marathon
sudo service marathon start
 [vagrant@node1 marathon]$ systemctl status marathon -l
marathon.service - Scheduler for Apache Mesos
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/marathon.service; enabled)
Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-12-11 22:38:36 UTC; 37s ago
Process: 30240 ExecStart=/usr/share/marathon/bin/marathon (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 30238 ExecStartPre=/bin/chmod 755 /run/marathon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 30235 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown marathon:marathon /run/marathon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 30234 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /run/marathon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 30240 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

[vagrant@node1 marathon]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

I followed the steps from [here](https://open.mesosphere.com/advanced-course/starting-marathon/).

I was not able to find answers online.

Comment: Can you share the logs?

Answer (score 1):

You can get marathon version with next command.

> $ rpm -qa marathon

And, you can find a error reason from `/var/log/all` maybe.